# Why i can't display an image to full screen in html?

Tags: html, css

The problem is, I want to make a full page background, but there's just a blank page. On the other hand, when I add

inside of background div, it displays, but only to the part of that.

HTML and CSS snippet:

```css
.bg{
  background: url(file:///D:/Dev/gamer/img/bg_1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="bg">
      <p>random text</p>
      <p>random text</p>
      <p>random text</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

The background on website:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.bg` element will only be as tall as the content inside of it: it does not grow to the viewport height unless styled specifically as such.

Either set the background image on the body element, or force `.bg` to grow to at least the current viewport height:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.bg {
  background: url('https://via.placeholder.com/4000x3000') no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <p>random text</p>
  <p>random text</p>
  <p>random text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the following code

**HTML**

```sh
    <div class="bg">
            <p>random text</p>
            <p>random text</p>
            <p>random text</p>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```sh
.bg{
      background: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: 100% 100%;
  height: 100vh
      
    }

*{
    margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your div is just as big as the content inside, if you want the picture to be on fullscreen change the css code tag from

```
.bg{
  //your code
}
```

to this

```
body{
//yourcode
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use pseudo selector properties for background image. Adjust size and opacity according to your need.

```
.bg::before{
content:"";
position: absolute;
background: url(file:///D:/Dev/gamer/img/bg_1.jpg) no-repeat center center/cover; 
height:100%;
width:100%;
z-index:-1;
opacity: 0.89;
}
```

Comment: i did it, but for some reason the background isn't 100% width, but stands in the middle of page

Comment: Try height and width in vh units like height:100vh and width:100vw.